# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier when async/await is present

Tags: android, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm getting this error when I run the app on Android 6 or 7 and android Oreo (8.1)

This is the error that shows in the console from logcat

```
 1-23 10:02:18.208 24346-24346/chess.pidoweb I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(10)] "The key "viewport-fit" is not recognized and ignored.", source: file:///android_asset/www/index.html (10)
11-23 10:02:18.644 24346-24354/? I/zygote64: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
11-23 10:02:18.880 24346-24428/? W/chromium: [WARNING:sqlite_persistent_cookie_store.cc(851)] Cookie database is too new.
11-23 10:02:18.881 24346-24428/? W/chromium: [WARNING:sqlite_persistent_cookie_store.cc(851)] Cookie database is too new.
11-23 10:02:23.006 24346-24364/? V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
11-23 10:02:24.519 24346-24346/? I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(588)] **"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier", source: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js (588)**
11-23 10:02:24.546 24346-24346/? D/XWalkCordovaUiClient: onPageLoadStopped(file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
11-23 10:02:24.546 24346-24346/? D/CordovaWebViewImpl: onPageFinished(file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
11-23 10:02:26.572 24346-24346/? W/zygote64: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
```

**Steps to Reproduce**

run the project on the device android [Android APi 23 to 27 get the same problem] with the comand ->ionic cordova run android

**Related Code**

the line [588] is this->
async revisa_sincro() { < .....code....> }

**Expected Behavior**

So, the real issue is this [async ] keyword that stop the app and showme white screen and
this error on console Uncaught SyntaxError.
If I remove every async code the app runs OK. but I really need this async !!!

**Additional Context**
How I cant get to solve this problem, there is any workaround ?

Ionic Info

```
    Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.0.0 (C:\Users\exe\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v8.11.2\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.0

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.1.2

System:

   NodeJS : v8.11.3 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 5.6.0
   OS     : Windows 10
```

**Packaje.json**

```
  {
  "name": "pidoionic",
  "version": "0.0.10",
  "description": "",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "config": {
    "ionic_webpack": "config/webpack.config.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.3",
    "@angular/animations": "7.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "7.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "7.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "7.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "7.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "7.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "7.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "7.1.0",
    "@ionic-native/app-version": "4.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "4.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "4.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/device": "4.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/fcm": "^4.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/firebase": "^4.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/google-analytics": "4.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/google-plus": "4.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/image-resizer": "4.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/local-notifications": "^4.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/native-storage": "^4.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "~4.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/sqlite": "^4.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/sqlite-porter": "^4.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/unique-device-id": "^4.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/youtube-video-player": "4.17.0",
    "@ionic/pro": "2.0.3",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "10.0.2",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "@types/google-maps": "^3.2.0",
    "angular2-uuid": "^1.1.1",
    "angularfire2": "^5.1.0",
    "cordova": "^8.0.0",
    "cordova-android": "7.1.2",
    "cordova-android-support-gradle-release": "^1.4.4",
    "cordova-browser": "5.0.3",
    "cordova-ios": "4.5.5",
    "cordova-plugin-app-version": "^0.1.9",
    "cordova-plugin-badge": "^0.8.8",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "^4.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-compat": "^1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-console": "^1.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "2.2.5",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^2.4.3",
    "cordova-plugin-googleplus": "~5.3.2",
    "cordova-plugin-local-notification": "^0.9.0-beta.2",
    "cordova-plugin-media": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-nativestorage": "^2.3.2",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-uniquedeviceid": "^1.3.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-youtube-video-player": "^2.0.0",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^2.5.1",
    "firebase": "^5.5.9",
    "global": "^4.3.2",
    "imagemin": "^5.3.1",
    "info.protonet.imageresizer": "^0.1.1",
    "ionic": "^3.20.1",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionic-tooltips": "^2.1.1",
    "ionicons": "4.2.6",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "local-storage": "^1.4.2",
    "moment": "^1.7.2",
    "ng-lottie": "^0.3.2",
    "ng2-reactive-forms-validators": "^1.1.0",
    "promise-polyfill": "8.1.0",
    "q": "^1.5.1",
    "run": "1.4.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.2",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.3.2",
    "sqlite3": "^4.0.0",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "typeorm": "0.2.8",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "7.0.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "7.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "7.1.0",
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.2.0",
    "@types/google.analytics": "0.0.39",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.30.11",
    "@types/node": "^10.5.4",
    "sql.js": "^0.5.0",
    "ts-node": "7.0.0",
    "typescript": "3.1.6"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [],
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
      "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {
        "GEOLOCATION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": " "
      },
      "cordova-plugin-console": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "info.protonet.imageresizer": {},
      "cordova-plugin-camera": {},
      "cordova-plugin-googleplus": {
        "REVERSED_CLIENT_ID": "com.googleusercontent.apps.781145103219-a87b3bd7d7858i8lrr2531nm8ml2bj6c",
        "WEB_APPLICATION_CLIENT_ID": "781145103219-vn75hrm8tv0b54hkck4dokv5nnr0pvao.apps.ioniusercontent.com"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
      "cordova-plugin-uniquedeviceid": {},
      "cordova-plugin-app-version": {},
      "cordova-plugin-nativestorage": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file": {},
      "cordova-plugin-youtube-video-player": {},
      "cordova-plugin-local-notification": {},
      "cordova-android-support-gradle-release": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION": "27.+"
      }
    },
    "platforms": [
      "browser",
      "ios",
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

Update:
**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2017"
    ],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "ES2017",
    "types" : ["node"],
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "src/**/*.spec.ts",
    "src/**/__tests__/*.ts"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": false
  }
}
```

Comment: Probably the runtime does not have native support for `async/await`  what `target` do you specify in your `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I've added the tsconfig.ts to the issue. ES2017 is present in tsconfig.json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things to check...

## ECMAScript Version

You can target different ECMAScript versions with the TypeScript compiler, so make sure you are targeting the version you are using at runtime. i.e. in your tsconfig.json file:

```
"target": "ES5"
```

This will then transform your async/await into a format usable in that runtime.

## JavaScript

If you have done the above and still have a problem, it is commonly caused by loading the TypeScript file `.ts` by accident at runtime, rather than the JavaScript `.js` file.

Comment: It might also work with `es2015` depends what kind of backward compatibility you want, `es5` is probably the safer option, but the js `async/await` code will be .. less than readable ..